# Android- Phonegap device width getting different values

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application in phonegap android.

I am trying to get the device width on device ready. I tried this code.

First time when application starts its giving (480, I am using samsung i9003 ) width ( alert ) and when I hit the backbutton and again running application its showing 320.

I has been stucked here .. please help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
<body onload="onLoad()">


<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="content">
<div id="justt"></div>
</div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }


    function onDeviceReady() {

    var width=0;
    width=$(window).width()

    $('#justt').css('width',(width)+'px');
    alert(width);
    }

    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are trying to create a div to set according to the mobile window you could jQuerymobile.js http://jquerymobile.com/download/ to create a div with different functionality according to the mobile window.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply and set according to your comment and place a main div ( named '.main') and take its width in javascript but first time its giving 480px. When I close the application and reopen its giving '320px'

My code like 

var width=$('.main').css('width');
 alert(width);

Comment: i am not a css person if u tell me what are u trying to achieve from this functionality i could suggest more acc answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to get a page content width:

```
var screenWidth = 0;
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    screenWidth = $('[data-role="page"]').first().width());
}).trigger('resize');​​​
```

This will give you page content width, even if page is resized.

You won't always get perfect results while getting viewport screen dimensions ($(window).width()), different  devices behave differently.

$(window).width() and $(window).height() will  give you the viewport dimensions, not the screen dimensions. [Here](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/) you will find detailed overview of this problem.